# MySQL - VARCHAR to DATE returns null

Tags: mysql, sql, string, date, datetime

Using Local Storage Connection within Toad Data Point.  It's set up to use MYSQL.

EXTRACT_DATE is varchar(20) in the format of:  08282020

Trying to change that format so it appears as 08/28/2020 in my results set.  However, I kept getting {null} returned.

I've tried a variety of different methods (see the code below)[image] but keep getting the same result.

```
SELECT
     EXTRACT_DATE,    
    DATE_FORMAT(EXTRACT_DATE, '%m/%d/%Y') AS NEW_DT,    
    STR_TO_DATE(EXTRACT_DATE, '%m/%d/%Y') AS NEW_DT2,    
    CONVERT (EXTRACT_DATE, DATE) AS NEW_DT3    
FROM USERTABLE   
GROUP BY EXTRACT_DATE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`STR_TO_DATE` turns a string into a date. To format the result, apply `DATE_FORMAT` like so:

```
select DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE('08282020', '%m%d%Y'),'%m/%d/%Y')  AS NEW_DT from dual
```

Answer (score 1):

It think it is simpler and more efficient to use sring functions:

```
concat_ws(
    '/',
    substring(extract_date, 1, 2),
    substring(extract_date, 3, 2),
    substring(extract_date, 5, 4)
) as new_dt
```

Or:

```
concat_ws(
    '/', 
    left(extract_date, 2), 
    substring(extract_date, 3, 2), 
    right(extract_date, 4)
) as new_dt
```

As for the query you wanted to write: you need to convert to a date first, then back to a string. So:

```
date_format(str_to_date(extract_date, '%m%d%Y'), '%m/%d/%Y')
```